# Cannot enable doctrine's entity manager

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I wanted to use Doctrine in my project, but I am not able to use Entity Manager.
I have created entites, repositories, config files and dbconnect but it seems that it's not done correctly.
Can you please check this code? Maybe I'm missing something really small.

My dbconnect file(it is bootstrapped in init.php):

```
<?php
namespace Projekt\Config;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array("Entity");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
'user'     => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname'   => 'projekt',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

My Repository example:

```
<?php

namespace Projekt\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Message
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class Message extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getMessage($id)
    {
        $message = $this->find($id);
        return $message;

    }
    public function getAllMessages()
    {

    }
    public function createMessage()
    {

    }
    public function updateMessage()
    {

    }
    public function deleteMessage()
    {

    }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to access a default or custom repository method I get this error:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), 
called in F:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\app\Controllers\Messages.php 
on line 15 and defined in F:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php on line 64
```

line 64 in EntityRepository.php is a __construct function that declares entitymanager, but it seems to not be working properly:

```
    public function __construct($em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
{
    $this->_entityName = $class->name;
    $this->_em         = $em;
    $this->_class      = $class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that i noticed:

1. Your path is relative. Im not sure but i always use complete path to the Entity folder. You can use __DIR__ to achieve that easily. Depending on your namespace it should look Like:

   `$paths = array(__DIR__ . "/../Repository")`;

Doctrine needs to know where to find your entities and repositories. Depending on your namespace i would think your Repository file exists in a folder named "Repository" and not "Entity".

2. Have you correctly defined an Entity Class? Your Repository class looks ok to me but it can only work if you have a valid Entity class.

You should not name your repository "Message". The Entity should be named "Message" and the repository should be named "MessageRepository".